# Any reason to set optimizeWrite = 'true', when autoCompact = 'auto' and no partitions are used

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I work with time series data and [Ingestion-Time Clustering](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/11/18/introducing-ingestion-time-clustering-dbr-112.html) (no partitioning) has proven to work well. In the [Databricks docs](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/tune-file-size.html#optimized-writes-for-delta-lake-on-databricks) is written *"Optimized writes are most effective for partitioned tables, as they reduce the number of small files written to each partition."*

Without any partitions, and with `autoCompact='auto`, I am wondering if there is any benefit of setting `optimizeWrite = 'true',`? The smaller file sizes that are written to disc directly from the executors will anyways be compacted with `autoCompact`. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, they could be compacted, but you need to take into account this statement from the docs:

> Auto compaction occurs **after a write to a table has succeeded** and **runs synchronously** on the cluster that has performed the write.

So the write time could increase. Plus, the weakest point of both auto-compact & optimized write is that they don't collocate the data like it's done with `OPTIMIZE ZORDER BY ...`.

But right now I would recommend to look onto Liquid Clustering ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/clustering.html), [blog post](https://www.databricks.com/blog/announcing-delta-lake-30-new-universal-format-and-liquid-clustering)) - it could be better from performance standpoint than both auto-compact and automatic or explicit optimization.

Comment: Thanks. I am reading ordered time series from a source DB on a batch process. Do you think without optimize write, the files would not be saved to disc in a sorted sequential order (if each executor has a different subset of the data)? Maybe optimize write would preserve the order of the data that is queried since everything is collected together before a write?

Comment: https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/11/18/introducing-ingestion-time-clustering-dbr-112.html may help if you have data clustered during ingestion.

Comment: yes ITC is what I'm using as per original question

Comment: @AlexOtt: Is it possible to use liquid clustering with the pyspark writestream api? And if not, how does one actually create a liquid clustered delta table from a python streaming dataframe?

Comment: You need to set `cluster by` on the non-partitioned table: https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/clustering.html

Comment: @AlexOtt The problem is that the pyspark writestream.start(path) creates the delta table, so when it is time to create the spark table its "too late", and I dont want to manually create the table schema in a SQL statement before I write the table (there are 40 columns). I found a hack, which is to create the sql table with just a single one of the columns (or a fake column which gets dropped), e.g. name: `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table1(name string) CLUSTER BY (name) LOCATION '/mnt/gold/business/test/delta'`, and then use `writeStream.option("mergeSchema", "true")..`. But that just feels wrong.